# How to take a project off Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to take off a project from Google app engine. Does anyone know how I can take it off? As you can see it says "Running" for both of the projects. How can I take them off?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the application, in the "My Applications" screen.

Select "Applications Settings"

About 3/4 of the way done the page you will see "Disable or Delete Application"

Click on "Disable Application", once it is disabled you can then choose to delete it.